# Converting month name to integer

Tags: vb.net, datetime, date, integer

I did a quick search for this and was surprised not to find it anywhere.

Basically looking to convert full month names (January, September, etc) to the equivalent number that would be used in mm/dd/yyyy format.

I can put together my own array and pull it out accordingly, but there has to be a quick and straightforward method already. Right?

Comment: the amount of characters it would have taken you to write extension method is probably equal to the length of your question :)

Comment: you're probably right. :) But this way, I get to give back to the community since it wasn't easy to find in the first place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the format string `MMMM` for the full name of the month.

See [custom DateTime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN.

```
Dim fullMonthName as DateTime
fullMonthName = DateTime.ParseExact("26 January 2010", "dd MMMM yyyy", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 23):

```
Dim monthName = "September"
Dim monthNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
```

If you are basing this on user input, I think this is the cleanest (especially if you are expecting multiple cultures to use this).  `DateTime.ParseExact` will allow you to input any sort of input and translate it into a `DateTime`, then pluck off whatever part of it you care about.

If, however, this isn't have on user input, I would have to suggest using some sort of static collection (whether a dictionary or an enum).

Comment: Looks good, but I think it should be monthName inside the ParseExact.

Comment: hi, but it give 1 digit month number, how can i get 2 digit month number?

Comment: @sephtian, it gives back an `Integer`.  If you want it as two digits, convert it to a string with that formatting, i.e. `monthNumber.ToString("00")`

Answer (score 2):

This is old but something I was looking for, just incase someone else comes looking I came up with an easy solution....

```
Dim sM as String = "Jun"
Dim iM as Byte = 0

iM = Month(sM & " 1, 2020")
```

iM will equal 6

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy, but isn't this exactly what an enum is for?  Maybe worth considering to keep the code as simple as possible.  http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/enum01.htm

Comment: VB is not my specialty, but in general, I wouldn't add an extra library solely to translate 12 strings into numbers.  Maybe if there were some other useful functions there...

Comment: I'm already using the DateTime library for other stuff, was just checking for a builtin way to do this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

well in my case I used this trick

1. Create 2 combobox
2. stuff combobox1 with the names of months
3. stuff combobox2 with years

and then this

```
    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        MsgBox(System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(ComboBox2.Text,   ComboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1), MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

This may sound long winded, why not use an IF Statement or Select Case.

```
If Month = "January" Then MonthNum = "1"
Else If Month = "February" Then .......
```