# convert date format MMMM yyyy to yyyyMM in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime-format

i have textbox that contain string month and year value, example: January 2010

but i want to save it into mysql database with format 201001 --->year and then number of month

how can i convert this string?

Comment: are you saving the date as string in mysql ? What is the column type in your database table

Comment: @Habib, yes i want to save it into mysql table, the coloumn type is varchar(6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258793/how-to-parse-a-month-name-string-to-an-integer-for-comparison-in-c), maybe you can try this:

```
Dim dateval As String = "January 2010"
Dim year As String = dateval.Split(" "C)(1)
Dim month As String = DateTime.ParseExact(dateval.Split(" "C)(0), "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month.ToString()

Dim yourdateval As String = String.Concat(year, month)
```

Comment: wow that's good idea, but it give me 1 digit month number, i want to get 2 digit month number :(

Comment: then maybe you can just make a condition to append a '0' before the month if it is a one digit number..

Comment: well i tought there's no other way :)

Comment: here the answer for 2 digit month number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662292/converting-month-name-to-integer/3662360#comment24026218_3662360