# How can I convert MMM format month to MM date in vb.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime

I need to get the number of the month from an abbreviation:

I have this :

```
Dim  monthname as string =  "Jun"
```

And I need to get this:

```
Dim monthnumber as integer =  6
```

How can I get this? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662292/converting-month-name-to-integer

Comment: I only need to transform the string month name to month number but without to pass the full date

Comment: Can you show how you're converting the string to a datetime at the moment?

Comment: Both the answers below quote the question I posted above! :)

Comment: @ScottPerham It's indeed similar, but reading the question, OP seems to have some difficulties modifying it from the full syntax to the short month syntax, that's why the repetition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ParseExact` to do that:

```
Dim  monthname as string =  "Jun"
Dim monthNumber as integer = DateTime.ParseExact(monthname , "MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
```

Alternatively, create a dictionary:

```
Dim months = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From
{{1, "Jan"}, {2, "Feb"}}, ...

Dim monthNumber = months(monthname)
```

Comment: Your first code works perfect to me, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this :

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Jun", "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

C#

```
var t = DateTime.ParseExact("Jun", "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var monthNum = t.Month;
```

VB:

```
Dim t = DateTime.ParseExact("Jun", "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim monthNum = t.Month
```

Answer (score 1):

I test the code working properly. Please also import System.Globalization.

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim  monthname as string =  "Jun"
        Dim monthnumber as integer = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMM", CultureIn

fo.CurrentCulture).Month 
        System.Console.WriteLine(monthnumber)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
    MonthsAndNmubers.GetMonthNumber("Jan")
End Sub

Public Class MonthsAndNmubers
    Private Shared ReadOnly monthsAndNumbers As IDictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)() _
 From { 
        {"Jan", 1}, _
        {"Feb", 2}, _
        {"Mar", 3}, _
        {"Apr", 4}, _
        {"May", 5}, _
        {"Jun", 6}, _
        {"Jul", 7}, _
        {"Aug", 8}, _
        {"Sep", 9}, _
        {"Oct", 10}, _
        {"Nov", 11}, _
        {"Dec", 12} _
    }
    Public Shared Function GetMonthNumber(month As String) As Integer
        Dim monthNumber As Integer = 0
        monthsAndNumbers.TryGetValue(month, monthNumber)
        Return monthNumber
    End Function
End Class
```